# Different views for different users in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, usersession

I am having a problem in ReactJS. I want to create a text editor ( with ReactQuill). So, I want different accounts for each user, such that, if one person creates a note and edits it in his account, the other person should not see this.for example this is my current stage - https://wright-text.web.app. After you create your account and login you would see a note called first note because that's the note I created. What should I do so that when you login you see no notes because you have not created a note, but when I login, I should see the note I had already created. How would I do this ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a scope to `notes` endpoint so that user could only `GET` notes, which they have created.

Comment: Can u just write some code to tell me how that would look like because I am new to this. Currently I am storing all the notes in a Google firebase database and retreiving it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add query parameters in the API you are fetching. For example, if you are fetching data via a GET request, add in some specific user id that you assign to your user upon validation and then fetch data of a particular user using that id as a query parameter on your API.